# Show PDF/print icons inside a template file

Tags: theming

I am using a template file to render a content type. So I print variables as with the following code.

```
print $node->body
```

I have installed the Print module, and I have selected the option to display print icons for this content type to, but the icons are not getting printed.

How can the icons be printed inside a template file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [README.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/print.git/blob/de4a43615194be1960393fab1b12c39e6742e354:/README.txt#l36) says

> Administration > Structure > Content types (admin/structure/types)
>   For each content type it is possible to enable or disable the
>   PF link via the "Show printer-friendly version link"
>   checkbox. (default: enabled) It is also possible to
>   enable or disable the PF link in individual comments via the
>   "Show printer-friendly version link in individual comments"
>   checkbox. (default: disabled)

[API](http://drupalcode.org/project/print.git/blob/de4a43615194be1960393fab1b12c39e6742e354:/README.txt#l62)

```
print_insert_link(), print_mail_insert_link(), print_pdf_insert_link()
```

> The *_insert_link functions are available to content developers that
>   prefer to place the printer-friendly link in a custom location. It is
>   advisable to disable the regular Printer-friendly link so that it is
>   not shown in both locations.

Take a look at [THEMEABLE FUNCTIONS](http://drupalcode.org/project/print.git/blob/de4a43615194be1960393fab1b12c39e6742e354:/README.txt#l85)

**It is a best Practice to read modules README.txt.**